# Bootstrap: Tabs inside a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, modal-dialog

I made a moda dialogl and now am trying to insert tabs into it, but having trouble getting the tabs to display content. Partial code of the tabs:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eGRmkzDvo4lYGCjzA5q7

How do I place tab pages inside a modal?

Comment: Please past the HTML (relevant) source here, because the markup on the plnunk looks all messed up and it may be the testing environment that messes it up.

Answer (score 14):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oj681B1YbLU1dJEiWHZp?p=preview

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
  <h3 ng-hide="newUser">Heading</h3>
</div>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
    <li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#access-security" data-toggle="tab">Access / Security</a></li>
    <li><a href="#networking" data-toggle="tab">Networking</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="details">

            Details tab
       <div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label">Instance Name</label>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="access-security">
        content 0
    </div> 
    <div class="tab-pane" id="networking">
        content 1
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You are missing the data-toggle attribute:

```
<li><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
```

And the active state for whatever tab you want to show up first:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
<div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
```

Comment: Added your suggestions. Still can't switch panes: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGRmkzDvo4lYGCjzA5q7

Comment: Your HTML is completely messed up -- fix it first. You also need to be using data-toggle="tab" instead of data-toggle="tabs".

Comment: Its Plunk. I'm not sure what "plink" is. I tore out a chunk of it and just saved the tabs portion. Its part of a larger application, so my first plunk was an attempt to mask a lot of it: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGRmkzDvo4lYGCjzA5q7                                          What ever changes are in the "plink" you did, I don't see. Try forking it and re-saving in the future. Anyway, I'm getting close; each page displays different content but the previous content remains. It must be a <div> I'm not closing?

Comment: I fixed it! http://plnkr.co/edit/nUL9svfqQYRkPqunkcGF I needed to wrap all tab-panes in a single .tab-content class, not one <div class="tab-content"> per pane.

Comment: Good to hear. I have never used plnkr before, I normally use JSFiddle. I guess I'll have to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: I use JSFiddle as well. I like Plunker because you can Fork. Thanks for your insight